# Azure function optional "middle" route parameter

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I want to make the "middle" route parameter optional in Azure functions. Ex:

```
 public static HttpResponseMessage MyFunction([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "SomeRoute/{MyOptionalRoute=int?}/AnotherRoute")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log,
        int MyOptionalRoute = 0)
    {
       //some magic
    }
```

This method works if i give MyOptionalValue a value. For example : /SomeRoute/123/AnotherRoute

But returns a 404 if i dont: Ex: /SomeRoute/AnotherRoute

Do anyone know if there is a way to get around this so that i dont have to create two seperate functions? I have been looking around and all i see is people using the optional route parameter as the last parameter in the sequence. Maybe i just dont know what keywords to google or is it just not possible?

Appreciate all help i can get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found, Azure function doesn't support optional “middle” route parameter yet. Only consecutive optional parameter like `SomeRoute/{MyOptionalRoute:int?}/{AnotherRoute:int?}` works.

Back to the point, find a workaround with [proxy for function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#advanced-configuration), see whether it meets your requirement.

Add a `proxies.json` to your function project, change file property `copy to output directory` to `copy if newer`.

[image]

See content below, I use 0 as the reserved number as the alternative of null value. Proxy directs `http://localhost/api/SomeRoute/AnotherRoute` to the real url `http://localhost/api/SomeRoute/0/AnotherRoute`, which matches the pattern of `SomeRoute/{MyOptionalRoute:int}/AnotherRoute`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "proxy1": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [ "GET" ],
        "route": "/api/SomeRoute/AnotherRoute"
      },
      "backendUri": "http://localhost/api/SomeRoute/0/AnotherRoute"
    }
  }
}
```